# How to get number of users followed by a particular twitter user using R?

Tags: r

I just want to know if there is any direct command or derivation in R to find the number of users followed by a particular user on twitter?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the `getFriends(n=NULL, ...):` method in the [twitteR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf) package.  The documentation states:

> Will return a list of user objects representing users this user
>   follows, up to a maximum of n values. If n is NULL, all friendss will
>   be returned